# Need help understanding the logic behind the intersection of infinite sets.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

As the post topic states, I need some help understanding the logic behind the intersection of infinite sets. I will take this time to thank anyone who reaches out with a comment or answer.

The following example has been taken from a real analysis book I've purchased.

Say the following sets exist,
$$ A_1 = N = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}\\
A_2 = \{2, 3, 4, ...\}\\
A_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... \}\\
A_n = \{n, n+1, n+2, ...\}$$

Now, i'm okay with this. $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = A_1$$
This is what I can't seem to grasp.
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = \emptyset$$

I can't make a mental picture of this since we have literally an infinite number of sets. I can see that $A_1 \cap A_2 = A_2$ applying that logic to each of these sets, which are by definition "infinite" there will always be some set $A_{n+1}$ for every $A_{n}$ So how can this ever be the empty set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If some number $k$ is in this intersection, then it is in all of the sets $A_n$. But $k$ is definitely not in $A_{k+1}$. Therefore no such $k$ exists; the intersection is empty.

The key is that for something to be in an intersection, it must be in each and every one of the intersecting sets.

Comment: Oh, okay that actually makes sense. So instead of looking at it from the point of view of 1 set at a time, I need to be looking at this from all sets! That clears this up so much. I can't thank you enough. Trying to put together the mental framework in order to understand the intersection of infinite sets has actually haunted me in the past. Very nice explanation.

Comment: @MichaelWalker Right. For finite intersections, you may be coming from an algorithmic point of view: Calculate $A_1 \cap A_2$ first, then $(A_1 \cap A_2) \cap A_3$ next,a.s.o. That works if you have a finite number of things to intersect, but that algorithm never terminates for an infinite one. You have to make arguments based on this answer: Find out which numbers are in **all** sets at the same time. You can't go **step by step** as in the finite case.

Comment: @Ingix Yeah, that makes way more sense. It's hard to get a grasp on these ideas. I am indeed coming from an algorithmic point of view by the way lol.